# Curl from shell, path with spaces

Tags: shell, curl

I have a folder path that contains spaces. I escaped the spaces with a back slash . The curl command works on the command line. If I run it within my script it crashes thinking the parts of the folder path are separate arguments.

The scripts goes through a directory and curls all the folders/files
code

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
   filepath=$(dirname "$file")
   #escape spaces
   filenew=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/\s/\\ /g')
   curl -k -T "$filenew" --ftp-ssl --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -u ${username}@${domain}:${pass} $ftpuploadpath  
 done < <(find ${folderpath} -type f -print0)
 echo "$file"
```

Error

```
   Transferring Sample_Project/folder\ spaces/test.docx
   0 Sample_Project/folder spaces/test.docx
   curl: Can't open 'Sample_Project/folder\ spaces/test.docx'!
   curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
   curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'spaces'
```

Comment: Quotes, people, quotes.

Comment: ...run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, fix everything it finds, then come back here if you still have trouble.

Comment: ...as for backslash literals, backslashes are only meaningful in context where they're syntax, not data. Any variable expansion result is pure data, as parameter expansion happens **after** syntax-level parsing is fully complete.

Comment: but I have quotes! I use shellcheck.net, love it. The escaped path seems to expand correctly (if I put echo infront of curl). How do go about this issue

Comment: `echo $file` -- no quotes. `${folderpath}` -- no quotes. `${username}@${domain}:${password}` -- no quotes. `$ftpuploadpath` -- no quotes.

Comment: ...and don't ever trust `echo`. Using `printf '%q\n'` if you want something actually reliable.

Comment: BashFAQ #50, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, is also directly relevant.

Comment: ...the point, though, was that your quotes (used correctly) are enough to ensure that arguments are passed to `curl` in one piece; adding (backslash escaping) syntax that only makes sense to bash and passing that syntax to `curl` in an argument (when `curl` doesn't in fact grok that syntax and expects a literal string assembled by the shell) doesn't do anyone any good.

Comment: `echo $file`, itself, munges the filename -- you have multiple spaces? They get broken into one. Any part of the name parses with a glob? It gets replaced with a list of files matching that glob, or (if the `nullglob` shell option is enabled), it's deleted. So `echo $file | anything` is evil in and of itself, if you don't want to potentially throw away data about what the original name was. (And if you read the POSIX spec for `echo`, it's even worse; any string with a literal backslash, for instance? Results completely undefined).

Comment: BTW, I meant what I said -- `printf '%q\n' curl ...` to test should give you a very good idea of why the old version was buggy (or `'%q '` if you want all the output on one line, though you'll want to put an `echo` or `printf '\n'` after it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes, people, quotes. Using `sed` to add syntactical elements (in this case, backslashes) to your data has absolutely no meaning, since syntax parsing happens long before parameter expansion occurs.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   filepath=$(dirname "$file")
   curl -k --ftp-ssl --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs \
     -T "$file" \
     -u "${username}@${domain}:${pass}" \
     "$ftpuploadpath" 
done < <(find "$folderpath" -type f -print0)
```

Note that:

- `-T "$file"` ensures that the filename is passed to `curl` as a single argument. No literal backslashes within the data need to be added to have this effect.
- `"${username}@${domain}:${pass}"` needs to be quoted, as a whole, to prevent any whitespace or glob characters inside any of these elements from impacting behavior via string-splitting and glob expansion (consider a password ending in `<space>*`; you don't want a list of filenames in the local directory added to your command line).

Comment: Thank you :D. I have learned a lot from this answer and your comments